# How to alias functions in building R package

Tags: r, devtools

In `packageName/man`  I want `?foo` and `?bar` to point to same documentation for these related functions.

Is it enough to, in `foo.Rd`:

```
\name{foo}
\alias{foo}
\alias{bar}
```

And then should I get rid of `bar.Rd`?  Or do I also have to put, in `bar.Rd`,

```
\name{bar}
\alias{bar}
\alias{foo}
```

And then how would `help()` know which documentation to use?

I started with `package.skeleton(code_files=...)`, which created many `.Rd` files that aren't necessary.  If I leave them in `install()` errors because they have empty titles.  I want to make sure that it is ok to delete many of them them and use `\alias{}` to group them into a few documents that I can spend a bit of time on.

Comment: Have you seen this fundamental document? https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Documenting-functions You just need `foo.Rd`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I am working my way through [this one](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf) which references it.  I will take a look.  I added a little context above.  Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Run a `R CMD check` on your tarball and the output shall set you free.